# How to remove white space under a table

Tags: html, css, vue.js

We need to display a data-table in a window that may need to have an X and/or Y overflow. When we don't have enough data to use the totality of the screen, we need to view white space, because setting another color would not be nice looking. But when the overflow is activated, the table should end with the last cell. However, a space is still visible, as seen on the attached picture. 
[End of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScrwW.jpg)

The structure of the table:

```
<div :id="getIdHTML('-search-list')" class="search-list">
    <data-table>
        <data-table-row :id="getIdHTML('-header-row')" class="header-row" :data="columns">
           <data-table-cell class="header-cell" v-for="(column, index) in columns" :key="index" :data="column">
               <p>{{ $t(column) }}</p>
           </data-table-cell>
        </data-table-row>
    </data-table>
    <data-table class="content-rows">
       <data-table-row class="content-row" v-for="(row, rowIndex) in rows" :key="rowIndex" :data="row.values" v-on:dblclick.native="openTabNotice(row)">
          <data-table-cell class="content-cell" v-for="(cell, cellIndex) in row.values" :key="cellIndex" :data="cell">
             <component v-model="cell.value" :is="cell.type" :fieldPrototype="cell.field" :maskType="'grid'" :inputMod="false" :entity="mask.entityTarget"
           :language="language" />
          </data-table-cell>
       </data-table-row>
    </data-table>
</div>
```

The style sheet:

```
.search-list {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(~'100% - 112px');
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.header-row {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: gray;
}

.content-rows {
   margin-top: 30px;
}

.header-cell {
  height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border-right: solid 1px lightgray;
}

.content-cell {
  min-height:30px;
}

.content-row:hover {
  background: @colorMouseHover
}

.header-cell p {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I tried setting the margin to 0, the padding to 0, changing *height* to *max-height*, setting a negative margin, but I can seem to get rid of this white space. It appears to be part of the div (it is attached to .search-list when looking in the explorer).

Comment: Are you using any additional libraries?

Comment: @AlanLarimer A lot of (it's a big project made in Spring/Vue.js), but not that could be related to table. I know that one of the previous developper tried to take one, but the whole doc was in chinese, so he retracted :/